# QPainter and paintEvent : what is the use of QPaintEvent *event?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a school project involving creating a  simple GUI and coloring graphs using a minimal number of colors. I am working with a classmate, and so far, we have laid out different ideas regarding how we will store the graphs in memory, and how to implement different coloration algorithms.

To create the GUI, we are using Qt, as I used it for another project before, it is free, and I generally find the documentation generally well detailed. Besides, I knew it had a drawing module, although I never used it.

After reading and the documentation and some examples, I was able to draw some basic shapes where I wished inside of a set area of a widget, and get them to correctly respond to resizing the widget.

To draw what I wish, I can write the paintEvent method this way, and just never use *event

```
void DrawArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
//method body
}
```

Or I can write it this way, and it works too

```
void DrawArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
//method body
}
```

So, i have two questions :

1. **How does the widget knows when to call the paintEvent method ?**
   If I'm not mistaken, every widget has a paint event, and I am
   overwriting it ? If it's wrong please correct me, maybe that is the
   reason why I don't really understand the way this pointer work.
2. **What is the QPaintEvent pointer ? (I mean, what does it represent ?)**

Thanks for any insight you may give me

Comment: [QPaintEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintevent.html). It provides additional information on the event, specifically what area of the widget needs to be repainted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So much text and so little questions...

1. You should learn about events handling in window systems (keywords are event loop, event queue and so on; in terms of Windows OS events are named "messages"). It is simple and useful thing to know.

   In short, your program asks OS for new tasks time after time. If they exist, some information about it is provided, and you should handle them. Otherwise OS stops the program until such tasks will appear.

   It means that OS notifies you to handle paint events when you are ready to do it.
2. `QPaintEvent` provides additional information about the event. At present it can give you a region to redraw. It may be used for painting optimization in some cases. But in simple cases it is not used.